# I am not able to connact to MongoDB atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect my MERN stack project to the MongoDB atlas. through this link

```
mongodb + srv://myUserName:myPassoword@cluster0.wbrda.mongodb.net/myCollectionName?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

this link was added to my application 2-3 days ago and it is working perfectly till 5 hours ago. Now it is not working, throwing error

```
not connected MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

this type of problem occurs to me a lot of time, but whenever I put a new link problem gets resolved but at this time I am not able to do it.

what is the permanent solution to that type of error?

please help me to get it out of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Atlas only allows client connections to a cluster from entries in the project’s IP Access List. Each entry should either be a single IP address or a CIDR-notated range of addresses.

You have to add your **IP** to the white list.
in your mongo account:
got to security section => Network access => ip access list.
then edit the ip:
you can either choose add current ip address choice, or you can add **0.0.0.0/0** manuelly(which includes your ip as well)

Comment: thanks for your support as of now it is working, whenever I will get this type of error again I will try it.